# Java QVariant equivalent?

Tags: java, qt, qt-jambi

Does java have a Data type that is similar to QVariant without using the java qt binding?

I want to have a Map< String, QVariant> so that I can have different data types for each value in the container.

Does JAVA have this?

P.S. JAVA noob!

Comment: No there isn't... Could be written but good luck with that. Do you mean to say values do not even have a common base type other than `Object`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure what you are looking for is [Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html), the "mother of all classes".
Use a `Map<String, Object>` and every value in the map can have a different type.

Comment: Yup this is it - not tested my use case but pretty sure